# data not binding to the textarea

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Vue, but I cannot bind the result to the textarea:

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="test" rows="6" v-model="test"></textarea>

  data: {
    test: ''
  }

          axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://localhost/test,
            responseType: 'json',
            data: {
              data: this.test
            }
          }).then(function (response) {
            this.test= response.data
          }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error)
          });
```

Comment: You haven't provide complete details, where `test` is initialized ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing that the axios request is inside any lifecycle hook or any method...`this` inside success callback does not point to the vue instance, that's why you cannot mutate the data property.

Use an arrow function instead:

```
axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://localhost/test,
            responseType: 'json',
            data: {
              data: this.test
            }
          }).then( (response) => {
            this.test= response.data
          }).catch( (error) => {
            console.log(error)
          });
```

Fat arrow functions `=>` bind `this` lexically, so you have `this` pointing the vue instance